# detectar click fuera de div JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un div modal que contiene un div contenedor:

```html
<div id="modal_global" style="width:100vw;height:100vh;position:fixed;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
<div id="modal_contenedor" style="min-width:500px;background:white;padding:50px;border-radius:4px;text-align:center;">Hola soy un contenido</div>
</div>
```

lo que deseo es detectar cuando dan click dentro del div #modal_contenedor y cuando den click fuera del div #modal_contenedor es decir detectar el click en #modal_global

quiero para que cuando al dar click en #modal_global se desaparesca, sin embargo cuando den click en #modal_contenedor no pase nada (el mismo resultado que cuando abres una foto en facebook y das click en el fondo negro se cierra la ventana modal)

lo que intente:

```
$("html").click(function() {
    alert("Click!");
});
$('#modal_contenedor').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

pero esto no me sirve ya que si pongo algun evento click en #modal_contenedor no me lo detecta por el e.stopPropagation(); y es muy deficiente estar escuchando todos los click en $("html");

de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No soy experto en el tema, pero por lo que he entendido quieres que al dar click en un div, este desaparezca, en cambio si es al contrario no realice ninguna accion. Se me ha ocurrido lo siguiente:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <div id="modal_global" style="width:100vw;height:100vh;position:fixed;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
            <div id="modal_contenedor" style="min-width:500px;background:white;padding:50px;border-radius:4px;text-align:center;">Hola soy un contenido</div>
            </div>
    

<script>
      $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
        var container = $("#modal_contenedor");
        var global = $("#modal_global");
        if (container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
           alert("HOLA SOY UN CONTENIDO");
        }else if(global.is(e.target) && global.has(e.target).length === 0){
            global.fadeOut();
        }
    });
    </script>
```

En este caso use `fadeOut();` que hace el div "modal_global" se desaparezca, pero se podria usar `hide();` en cambio en la seccion de container que colocado un alert, indicado que este ha sido pulsado. Pero solo podrias dejarlo en blanco para que no haga ninguna funcion.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar o darte una idea de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: esta solucion es igual que la mia "practicamente", pero lo que yo no queria era que se me vallan recursos escuchando los click en document, queria algo mas "lite"

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que el `Global` desaparesca y el `Contenedor` se quede quieto puedes hacer lo siguiente, **solo seleccionar el div global y no todo el HTML**

```js
$('#modal_global').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('Soy el contenido Global!');
  $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('#modal_contenedor').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('Soy el contenedor 01')
});

$('#modal_contenedor_cont').click(function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('Soy el contenedor 02')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal_global" style="width:100vw;height:100vh;position:fixed;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
<div id="modal_contenedor" style="min-width:300px;background:white;padding:50px;border-radius:4px;text-align:center;">Hola soy un contenido

<div id="modal_contenedor_cont" style="min-width:50px;background:white;padding:50px;border-radius:4px;text-align:center;background-color:red;">Hola soy un contenido 02</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ahora como me comentastes si quieres que dentro del `div contenedor` se escuchen x `clicks` debes agegar la condicion `e.target !== this` a cada div o elemento con funcion `click` para que se escuche independientemente de los demas

Comment: el codigo funciona perfectamente salvo por un detalle, como tiene e.stopPropagation(); al poner un on.click a cualquier elemento dentro de contenedor no me lo detecta o mejor dicho anula el click debido al e.stopPropagation();

Comment: @IntruzO ya modifique mi codigo sin usar el `e.stopPropagation()`, en vez de eso, debes el `e.target` en cada `click` que haras para que se lea independientemente de otros `clicks`

Comment: me funciona perfectamente amigo, usé este codigo:

$('body').on("click","#modal_global",function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {return;}
  $(this).remove();
});

$('body').on("click","#modal_contenedor",function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {return;}
});

$('body').on("click","#modal_contenedor",function (e) {
  if (e.target !== this) {return;}
});

ya que mi #modal_global es generado dinamicamente con jquery y si no le pongo $("body").on("click".... no me detecta el elemento #modal_global ni #modal_contenedor
e notado tambien que no me detecta el click en #modal_contenedor

Comment: digo que no lo detecta porque no me sale el alert() pero esta bien porque cumple con su objetivo de cerrarse al dar click en #modal_global y de quedarse tal cual al dar click en #modal_contenedor